# Java FX Color of Label is forgotten

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I've observed the following problem in simple JavaFX project. In NetBeans I've create simple FXML project. It contains the FXML file

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sensordemo.MainController">
    <children>
      <VBox blendMode="COLOR_DODGE" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="12.0" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="169.0">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="147.0" prefWidth="109.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="XXXXX" textFill="#8c5123">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="83.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="YYYYY" textFill="#23288d">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="18.0" />
                     </font></Label>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="167.0" prefWidth="83.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="ZZZZZ" textFill="#23288d">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>

    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The color of label correctly is correctly displayed in FX Scene Builder, but if I use preview feature of Scene Builder is see wrong color of label. I see white font on gray backend. In case I create the build of this simple project I see the same wrong colors. What is the reason of this issue? Seems to me the correct definition of colors is not included in build.
I use

1. Netbeans 8.1
2. Java SDK 8 64-bits.
3. Windows 7 64-bits

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the expected output? In SceneBuilder I don't see anything. Is this expected? What is the expected background color?

Comment: Expected output is in the fiirst case I would like to see red font on white background in other cases I would like to see blue font on white background. When I start application I seewhite font on gray background. Expected output is

Comment: Have how any css for modifing the VBOX background?How you expect it to change?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid somehow SceneBuilder got the effect wrong.

You're using the [`BlendMode.COLOR_DODGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html#COLOR_DODGE).

From the javadoc:

> The bottom input color components are divided by the inverse of the top input color components to produce the resulting color.

So given the background color component `B` and the text color component `T` the component of the output `P` is calculated as

```
P = min(B / (1 - T), 1)
```

*(Components in range `[0, 1]` here)*

None of the color components of the colors you use for the `Label` text color is darker than `0.13`, so `B / (1 - T) >= B / 0.87` which means any background color with components `(0.87, 0.87, 0.87)` or brighter will display as white color. This is the case for the default background in a JavaFX scene. So white is the expected color.

Maybe you should to use a different `blendMode` or change the `AnchorPane` background to something darker to see the colors of the text:

```xml
<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: #888;" ...
```

---

My guess is that you do not need a `blendMode` different to the default (`SRC_OVER`), but just need to adjust the background of the `AnchorPane`:

```xml
<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: white;" id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
      <VBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="12.0" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="169.0">
         ...
      </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to get the expected result is:

> ~>1)  If you will keep that style this is recommended

In the SceneViewer manually add the background color of each VBox or Label  using inline css:

```
-fx-background-color:white;
```

> ~>2)  Best practice

Add a StyleClass on each VBox or Label through `SceneViewer` and use an external css file for your application:

```
   .styleClassName { 

        -fx-background-color:white; 

     }
```

> ~>3)

You can add a unique id for each VBox or Label you have and modify their style into the Java code using:

```
elementID.setStyle(" -fx-background-color:white; ");
```

**Mention that:**
The default background color of most JavaFX layouts is like gray so you have to change it.